# How to acquire virtual address space and separately provision memory on Win64, MacOS and Linux?

Tags: memory-management, mmap, tlb, virtual-address-space, address-space

I would like to build a memory allocator to manage a large chunk of non-shared, linear address space (*e.g.* 32GB).  I need to run this on the Big-3 operating systems, but I can live with having OS-specific code.

**Functionality desired:**

- At start, acquire a 2^N byte contiguous region of virtual address space aligned
  on a 2^N byte boundary
- Initially, the entire region should be inaccessible (*i.e.* touching any address
  within this region should result in that OS's equivalent of a SEGV)
- Over time, from the base of this region (the lowest address), I will grow the
  portion that should be made accessible (*i.e.* allocate backing store, provision
  PTEs)
- It is acceptable, while running, to encounter a failure due to backing store
  exhaustion

**Bonus points:**

- It is desirable that, initially, no backing store be reserved
- Unprovisioning the entire region without releasing the address space
- Encourage use of larger pages and TLB entries

**Questions:**

- I know that I can implement this scheme using mmap on Linux.  Is it doable on
  Win64 and MacOS?
- If yes, what primitives / system calls should I be looking at?
- How can I best achieve 2^N byte alignment when initially acquiring address space?

Comment: On Windows, you can use VirtualAlloc to reserve address space or commit memory into it. VirtualAllocEx lets you pick the starting address.